# Efficient way (using apache POI) to read an XLSX, replace the first row and write the result?

Tags: excel, apache-poi, xssf

It seems the best option is to use the XSSF and SAX (Event API) but the docs aren't really that good and I can't find a simple example for my needs:

I need to read a XLSX file, read the first row and first cell and then replace the text there (something like Title: TODO) and write the final file (Title: example).

This must be very efficient in terms of memory-use. I don't mind the speed performance, just memory usage.

Currently using apache poi 3.8

Comment: did you try XSSFSheet.getFirstRowNum() and Row.getFirstCellNum()